# How to keep alive thin server using a cron job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, thin

I have a RoR3 website that is hosted by HostingRails and is using thin server.
I noticed that every so often, the thin server goes down and I can't find a reason for it.

Writing cron jobs are not my strong suite but, from research, I found cron jobs can be used to check the server status and restart if down.

So, my question is, how to write a script that will run a cron job checking if a thin server is down, and if it is, to restart it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is related to your issue.

Make sure you start thin with the -d option.

-d == Daemonize to run in background

I hope this helps.